# limits and the definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am working on proving if a limit exists.

the sequence $s_n=|\frac{n+1}{n}-1|$ has a limit as $n$ approaches infinity, and this limit is s=1.

My work:

A sequence $(s_n)$ of real numbers is said to converge to the real number $s$ provided that
for each $ε > 0$ there exists a number $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|s_n −s|<ε$.

impose $|s_n-s|<\varepsilon$. which implies $n>1/\varepsilon$ $|\frac{n+1}{n}-1|< \varepsilon$ which means $n>1/\varepsilon$

Now based on our definition, we want $N>1/\varepsilon$. My first misunderstanding is here. I was told that this means for all natural numbers bigger than $n$, the distance between the corresponding element of the sequence and your candidate limit is less than the epsilon given. What does this mean?

Here's the proof:

let $\varepsilon>0$. choose $N>1/\varepsilon$
in this case, if $s=1$,
$|sn-s|=|\frac{n+1}{n}-1|=|1/n|=1/n\tag{2}$
but if $n>N$, then $1/n<1/N$, and also by choice of $N$, $1/n<\varepsilon$, so $|sn-s|<\varepsilon$

My second problem is here. I don’t understand $(2)$. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $S_n=n+\frac{1}{n}$ converges $1$?

Comment: You appear to have mistakes in your notation. For example |n+1/n-1| equals $|n+\frac{1}{n}-1|$ which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I think I made all the necessary corrections

Comment: the sequence you have now in the first line is different from the one you had previously, and  the one you have now is just $s_n=\frac{1}{n}$, which approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if your formatting was clearer; it is somewhat confusing to read as it is now.

But we want to show that the sequence $$s_n=\frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{n}$$ converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By the Archimedean property of the real numbers, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $0<\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon$. Now, for all $n\geq N$, we have $$|s_n-1|=\bigg|\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)-1\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{1}{n}\bigg|=\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon $$ since $n\geq N\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N}$.

No matter what 'epsilon tolerance' one chooses, one can 'look' far out enough into the tail of the sequence and make the distance between $1$ and the elements of $(s_n)$ less than the given epsilon tolerance for all elements of $(s_n)$ after we pass some $s_N$ in the sequence.

Comment: How is it true that if n>N, then (1/n)<(1/N)

Comment: @LavoriziaVaughn try some examples. $100>10$ and $1/100<1/10$. otherwise you could do some proofs by contradiction to see for yourself.